# Timer to refresh charts in c#

Tags: c#, charts

I have created a chart which receives its data from a SQL Server database. Whenever I save new data into the database, all the reports get updated, but the chart does not update until I exit the application and log in again. I decided to use Timer in C# to automatically refresh the chart every 5 seconds.

```
//this is to invoke the timer as soon as the application launches.
      public MDIParent2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myTimer.Enabled = true;
            myTimer.Start();
        }
//this is my timer event
private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.Refresh();
            MessageBox.Show("Refreshed!");//this was added to determine if the timer is working
        }

//this lets me stop the timer

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myTimer.Stop();
        }


//this lets me resume the timer       
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myTimer.Start();
        }
```

I get the message "Refreshed!" every 5 seconds, but chart is still not refreshed. Can someone please assist?

Comment: I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: @GrantWinney, I use databinding and this was auto-generated        {
                this.view_counselorTableAdapter.Fill(this.genderCounselorChartDataSet.View_counselor);
                    this.view_genderTableAdapter.Fill(this.genderChartDataSet.View_gender);

         }

Answer (score 0):

replace this.refresh() with [Chart Object].refresh()

Comment: should I replace the [Chart Object] with the name of my chart? Example, chart1.Refresh();? If so, I have tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Which chart control you are using ?

Comment: I'm using pie chart and column chart